# Is "The customer experiences that the connection has been failed by unknown factor." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

For this sentence:

> *"The customer experiences that the connection has been failed by unknown factor."*

the following sound unnatural to me – but is it still grammatically correct?

> - a. "The customer experiences that..."
> - b. "...has been failed by..."

Comment: As regular contributors already know, proofreading questions are off-topic _unless the cause of confusion is identified_. In this case, had the question merely asked, "Is this grammatically correct?" I would have expected to see close votes. Instead, the O.P. rightly pinpointed the suspect phrases, and got two detailed answers in less than one hour. Vincent, nice job, and welcome to ELL. Other newcomers to the ELL community might want to make a mental note.

Answer (score 1):

As for *the customer experiences that*, that is fine. You could change *experiences* to *notices* or *finds*, but that is not necessary.

As for *has been failed*, that is a different thing.

Strictly speaking I assume it could be grammatically correct, but I highly doubt the meaning is the one you want to convey.

You could use *fail* in the passive form like this:

> The test was failed by the student.

This is an unusual way of saying:

> The student failed the test.

Now, did your "unknown factor" fail the connection? Was the "unknown factor" trying to achieve the connection? I doubt it.

Normally, a connection does not *get* failed, it *fails*. So simply use the active form:

> The connection failed due to an unknown factor.
>   The connection failed because of an unknown factor.

**Factor** is a bit hazy in this context, by the way. I would suggest that if you do not know what caused the connection to fail, just say you do not know the *reason*:

> The connection failed for an unknown reason.

Comment: FWIW, I read "has been failed by" in the sense of "the student has been failed by the teacher". That is, "fail" meaning "to determine to have failed", definition 13. at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fail. The sentence still doesn't make sense, but it's another thing to consider before deciding that it doesn't :-)

Answer (score 1):

> The customer experiences that the connection has been failed by unknown factor.

Your right, the original sounds unnatural. I see three problems, and you've correctly identified two of them. I'll address them each individually.

---

> The customer **experiences** that the connection has been failed by unknown factor.

I don't think *experiences* is a very fitting verb in this context. On a personal level, systems failures are something you *observe*, not *experience*. That said, this is a tricky one, because it *is* okay for a company to issue a statement saying:

> We have experienced too many system failures over the past month.

because the speaker is talking from a corporate perspective, not a personal one. From a customer perspective, though, I'd say that customers can experience *heartache*, *frustration*, or *disappointment*, but not *system failures*, or *lost connections*. Instead, I would choose a verb such as *notices* or *observes*.

---

> The customer experiences that the connection **has been failed** by unknown factor.

This is the wrong verb tense. When a system crashes, and we use the verb *fail*, we say that it *has failed*, not that it *has been failed*. Once again, though, this is tricky, because we *can* say:

> The system *has been **down*** for over two hours!

---

> The customer experiences that the connection has been failed **by unknown factor**.

I don't think *by* is the right preposition here. I think you are trying to say *because of* (or *due to*). If you want to stick with a preposition, use *for* instead of *by*.

Also, I think you need to put the word *some* in front of *unknown factor*, or else make it plural. When words such as *reason* or *factor* are in a prepositional phrase, we generally use *some* (or an indefinite article) when using the singular. For example, I might say either of these:

> For some unknown reason, the connection was lost.
>   For unknown reasons, the connection was lost.

But I would not say:

> For unknown reason, the connection was lost.

---

Put all of these changes together, and we get:

> The customer <strike>experiences</strike> **notices** that the connection has <strike>been</strike> failed <strike>by</strike> **because of** some unknown factor.

Or, without the crossed-out words:

> The customer notices the connection has failed because of some unknown factor.

As mentioned previously, the phase *due to* could be used in place of *because of*.

---

By the way, I agree with oerkelens; at the end of the sentence, I think *reason* or *cause* would be a better word than *factor*. My final edit would be:

> **The customer notices the connection has failed due to unknown causes**.